# Codes do not animate changes in shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

I  have tried to learn the shiny structure to develop my plot. After hours of working on this, I got the plot of interest, but when I change the values, I do not see any change in the plot.

Thank you in advance!

Here are the codes:

```html
library(shiny)

df <- data_frame(x = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O"
),
y = c(45,55,66,55,45,45,50,50,50,64,44,60,50,50,45))

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("letters"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$b("Data:"),
      textInput("x", "x", value = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O", placeholder = "Enter letter separated by a comma, A,B,C"),
      textInput("y", "y", value = "45,55,66,55,45,45,50,50,50,64,44,60,50,50,45", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points, e.g. 50, 55.5, 5, 5.03, etc."),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  ))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    df2 <- ave(df$y, df$y, FUN = seq_along)
    plot(df2 ~ df$y, df, pch = df$x, ylim = c(1, 20), ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
    axis(1)
    mu <- mean(df$y)
    abline(v = mu, col = "red")
    text(mu, 20, paste("Avg time:", mu), adj = -0.1, col = "red")
  }) 
})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The key thing missing is you need to use the variables `input$x` and `input$y` in your reactive function `renderPlot` somewhere. Are you looking to filter the dataset by these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the dataframe pass `input$x` and `input$y` to make a dataframe inside the server to get it to react to changes. For example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("letters"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$b("Data:"),
      textInput("x", "x", value = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O", placeholder = "Enter letter separated by a comma, A,B,C"),
      textInput("y", "y", value = "45,55,66,55,45,45,50,50,50,64,44,60,50,50,45", placeholder = "Enter values separated by a comma with decimals as points, e.g. 50, 55.5, 5, 5.03, etc."),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot"),
      "This is a brief description text"  # can add other elements
    )
  ))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    df <- data_frame(x = input$x %>% str_split(",", simplify = TRUE) %>% str_trim(),
                     y = input$y %>% str_split(",", simplify = TRUE) %>% str_trim() %>% as.numeric())
    
    df2 <- ave(df$y, df$y, FUN = seq_along)
    plot(df2 ~ df$y, df, pch = df$x, ylim = c(1, 20), ylab = "", axes = FALSE)
    axis(1)
    mu <- mean(df$y)
    abline(v = mu, col = "red")
    text(mu, 20, paste("Avg time:", mu), adj = -0.1, col = "red")
  }) 
})



shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(two extra packages used here: `dplyr` and `stringr`)

Comment: Ah I see - you want to change the dataframe itself? Will amend code.

Comment: No problem! If you want to add static text you can type it in " " marks in the ui part under the graph (after a comma after the closing `plotOutput` bracket). If you want it reactive then use the same `textInput` field and pass through the server to `renderText/textOutput` in the same way you've used inputs and outputs for the graph above (but as separate from the plot object you've made. Is that helpful?

Comment: Have added a little "This is a brief description text" paragraph under the graph - is that helpful?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here? But it might be a different question if the input reactivity question is resolved. comments sections aren't always the best place for further discussion. Do mark the question as completed if it's answered as to how to make outputs respond to user inputs and you can set up another one if there's a specific input/interactivity you can't get to work.

Comment: You can delete `plotOutput` from the ui section and it will disappear if that's what you mean?

Comment: I've removed the sample image of the graph.